# Failed to get properties: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out

Tags: linux, rhel7, systemctl

Getting the below error while running `systemctl status` commands in my RHEL 7 linux server.

```
# systemctl status docker.service
Failed to get properties: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out
```

I see the login also is slow. What could be the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Reboot the server, this should fix the problem.

Comment: Can you add your reasoning behind this?

Comment: The beauty of this situation, is that you can't even gracefully reboot: `Failed to start reboot.target: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out`

Comment: can someone please share a permanent solution to this problem  ?